# is it possible to make this method reusable for other classes if possible then let me know in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

### i have implemented this in other statefull class but is show error as class display widget function but i want to display this function and make it reuseable for other classes aswell....................................................................

```
_openCustomDialog() {
 showGeneralDialog(
    transitionBuilder: (context, a1, a2, widget) {
      return Transform.scale(
        scale: a1.value,
        child: Opacity(
          opacity: a1.value,
          child: AlertDialog(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            actions: [
              Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 310,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 20,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image: NetworkImage(img),  
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        )),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              gradient: LinearGradient(
                                  colors: [
                                Colors.blue[900],
                                Colors.blue[700],
                                Colors.transparent,
                                Colors.transparent,
                                // Colors.transparent
                              ],
                                  begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                                  end: Alignment.bottomRight)),
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Icon(
                                Icons.favorite_border_outlined,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(width: 12),
                              Icon(
                                Icons.download_outlined,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
                            gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
                              Colors.blue[200],
                              Colors.blue[500],
                              Colors.blue[800]
                            ])),
                        child: TextButton(
                          child: Text('back',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 13,
                                  fontFamily: 'LobsterTwo Bold',
                                  color: Colors.white)),
                          onPressed: () async {
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
    barrierDismissible: true,
    barrierLabel: '',
    context: context,
    pageBuilder: (context, animation1, animation2) {});
}
```

### .......................................................................................................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 options that requires renaming the function to not have the _ in the beginning
1- put it in a file by itself
2- put it at the end of the file (or outside your classes)
3- make it static (my least favorite solution)

You will need pass context as a parameter

```
openCustomDialog(BuildContext context) {
```